# qgis2web hangs with large layer

Tags: qgis2web

I am trying to convert multiple raster layers with hundreds of files in each into web tiles.

qgis2web start processing, at "exporting layer1 to PNG" it shoots the CPU to 100%, hours later it crashes with python error.

here is the complete result:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/p6/qvt9dldn13sckjk_2jf2hxf80000gn/T/ttn10rp01545831356_piped.tif'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/igzebedze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/utils.py", line 399, in exportRaster
    processing.run("gdal:warpreproject", warpArgs)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 96, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 139, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT: /var/folders/p6/qvt9dldn13sckjk_2jf2hxf80000gn/T/ttn10rp01545831356_piped.tif not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/igzebedze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 335, in saveMap
    feedback=self.feedback)
  File "/Users/igzebedze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/olwriter.py", line 91, in write
    folder=dest_folder)
  File "/Users/igzebedze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/olwriter.py", line 130, in writeOL
    popup, json, restrictToExtent, extent, feedback, matchCRS)
  File "/Users/igzebedze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/utils.py", line 225, in exportLayers
    exportRaster(layer, count, layersFolder, feedback, iface, matchCRS)
  File "/Users/igzebedze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/utils.py", line 401, in exportRaster
    shutil.copyfile(piped_file, piped_3857)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/p6/qvt9dldn13sckjk_2jf2hxf80000gn/T/ttn10rp01545831356_piped.tif'

Python version: 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 03:02:14) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] 
QGIS version: 3.4.1-Madeira Madeira, exported 
Python Path:
* /Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
* /Users/igzebedze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
* /Users/igzebedze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
* /Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
* /Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/D/Python/3.6
* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip
* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
* /Users/igzebedze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
* /Users/igzebedze/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
* /Users/igzebedze/Dropbox (Personal)/devel/zemljevidi/tiles

Comment: QGIS2web is not ment to create webtiles. It will copy the big tif into a big png. What would you like to accomplish?

Comment: i'd like to create a set of xyz tiles to use in a browser map. i thought this was the way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, qgis2web was designed to export static maps (exporting your shapefiles/geopackages to geojson) and trying to translate your current style setting into a leaflet/openlayers based style. the basemap is fetched form other sources like OSM, Google, Esri.

**QGIS2web is not meant to convert a raster to xyz tiles to serve as a basemap.**

For creating a xyz-tiled basemap from a raster you should have a look at [gdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203950/create-blue-marble-xyz-tiles) or [tilemill](http://www.digital-geography.com/visualizing-nasa-black-marble-with-tilemill-and-leaflet/).

Comment: If you want to create xyz tiles the are are a couple of options the easiest one is to use https://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html which will also create a static html page. Alternatively you can install serve up the raster layer through GeoServer. If you prefer to use QGIS you can use QGIS server + Mapproxy